# How do I let a service wait for an out-of-band process to complete?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, java-8

I have a service, living on Server 1. Let's call it `PDFService`. `PDFService` takes documents and stitches them together in a single PDF.

However, `PDFService` only knows about document ids. It relies on Server 2 to get the actual content of the documents.

At the start of `PDFService`'s process, it will collect document ids in batches. When it has a batch, it will send an async request for each id in the batch to a queue on Server 2 (getting back a 204). It will then continue collecting more batches and repeat.

Once all the batches have been collected and sent off, `PDFService` will start the stitching process.

In the meantime, none, some, or all of the documents may have been processed by Server 2 and returned to Server 1. Server 2 may return documents in a different order than it received them in. (Each document will take a different amount of time to compile and return.)

Server 1 must stitch them in the same order they were sent off. So, it must wait for document 1, stitch it, wait for document 2, stitch it, etc.

As of now, I have a `DocumentManager` class that will keep all the document ids in a `Map` with `null` values. When the completed document comes back from Server 2, the `Map` is updated with an actual value (an object holding the document's contents). This is obviously wrong, as then `PDFService` would have to use `while null` + `sleep`, which is bad.

**My question is: How do I let PDFService "wait" for each document, if it needs to?** Adding `CompletableFuture` objects to my `Map` seems promising, but I can't figure out how to use it or if that is even the correct approach.

*(This is one of my first questions, please provide constructive feedback!)*

Comment: I should note that I do not have control over Server 2. It has an internal queue that I access via ReST - I am unable to subscribe to its queue in the traditional manner. It responds to me via endpoints that I have to implement according to their specs.

Comment: Listeners (e.g. for JMS) actually use "pull" model and send request to get message (if any) about every 100 ms. So you can do that too. But if it is "push" model when Server2 sends kind of POST response with result to your another endpoint, then it can be  even easier for you. By sending batch to Server2 make a thread which will scan responses from response endpoint, sleep for some time and loop again until all results gathered... that is almost it. Then complete process on Server1 and free that thread. You may have Thread Pool there if you'd like. Something like that...

Answer (score 1):

H-m-m...
I can recommend you to look at some Enterprise Integration Frameworks like "Spring Integration", "Apache Camel", "MuleSoft" and some others. Such framework can take care about all waiting, asynchronous, parallel, aggregation etc. things and it will be much easier for you.

in general

> it will send an async request for each id in the batch to a **queue** on Server 2

You already mentioned a queue, so using a JMS queue(s) is one of the possible solution.

- Server1 sends documentId for Server2 into JMS queue
- Server2 listens on queue and responds with actual document 
  (there are number of possibilities how server can reply on JMS message)
- Server1 listens for response then stitches all of them when all received

But with EIP framework JMS is not only one possibility - as example for the batch it could be synchronous but parallel calls to Server2...

BTW: build such thing from scratch without any frameworks (EIP and/or JMS) is very painful and has no sense to do that.

Comment: Ah, I never even thought about using a queuing system on Server 1! I will definitely look into this and what it could bring me.